# Print margin at position Xpx (visual only)

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinyMCE v4. Is it possible to create a print margin (visual only) at custom position (e.g. 700px)? In the image below, print margin is marked with orange color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has no built in way to do this.  You could use CSS to apply something to the `<body>` of the document inside the editor to get that effect.